# Version of the Vitali Covering Lemma

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $\mathcal{B}$ be a collection (not necessarily finite) of open balls in $\mathbb{R}^d$ with the property $| \cup_{B\in \mathcal{B}} B|<\infty$. Prove that there exists a countable subcollection $\{B_i\}_{i\in I}$ of pairwise disjoint balls in $\mathcal{B}$ such that the following two conditions are satisfied:

1. For every $B\in \mathcal{B}$, there is $i\in I$ such that $B\subset 5B_i$;
2. There exists a positive constant $C_d$ depending only on $d$ such that 
   $$\left|\bigcup_{B\in \mathcal{B}}B\right|\leq C_d \sum_{i\in I}|B_i| .$$
   Here $|U|$ denotes the Lebesgue measure of the set $U$.

**Attempted Solution**
Using Zorn's lemma it is possible to to find a subcollection that satisfies condition 1 (such a proof is well known, and can be found on the wikipedia page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_covering_lemma). Given property $1$, property $2$ can easily be proven using subadditivity:
$$\left|\bigcup_{B\in \mathcal{B}}B\right|\leq \left|\bigcup_{i\in I}5B_i\right|\leq\sum_{i\in I}|5B_i|=5^d\sum_{i\in I} |B_i|. $$
The only difficulty I am having is showing that the resulting collection can indeed be taken to be countable, any advice on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not only *can* it be taken to be countable, it *must* be countable!

Since $\mathbb{R}^d$ is separable (has a countable dense set, namely $\mathbb{Q}^d$), any family of pairwise disjoint (nonempty) open sets is countable.  (Each open set in the family has nonempty intersection with $\mathbb{Q}^d$, no two distinct sets in the family can contain the same point of $\mathbb{Q}^d$.)